# How to Count Days Present In Values of a Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a field called `CreatedOn` with values like :

```
2012-06-19 08:42:48.000
2012-06-19 08:43:05.000
2012-06-19 08:43:27.000
2012-06-19 08:53:22.000
...
2012-06-20 09:20:54.000
2012-06-20 09:21:13.000
...
2012-06-21 10:02:17.000
2012-06-21 11:43:19.000
...
2012-06-22 12:00:40.000
2012-06-22 12:11:56.000

... (weekend)


2012-06-25 13:00:13.000
2012-06-25 13:12:24.000
...
2012-06-26 13:41:27.000
2012-06-26 13:41:44.000
2012-06-26 13:42:01.000
```

I would like the output to show -- `6` (days). But its not as simple as not counting weekends, as there may be other days that are not counted, best way to make sure is to do it based on the data.

Any ideas?

I was able to make : `DATEDIFF(w, MIN(CreatedOn), MAX(CreatedOn))` but as stated its inaccurate, it shows dates that have no corresponding data,

Comment: Martin, its Sql Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 2008+

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (CAST (CreatedOn AS DATE))) AS NumberOfDays
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to count days that had any activity? The below is slightly more complex than needed:

```
select COUNT(*) from (
select DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,CreatedOn),0) as dt,COUNT(*) as cnt
from Table
group by DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,CreatedOn),0)
) dayCounts
```

But you can re-use the inner query if you need more detail about particular days.